# How to align the div as vertical with up and down button using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have 3 div's that position is absolute in css. What I want now is to make them vertical. And there is also a Up and down button. When I click the up button the div should go up(swap div) and when I click the down(swap div) button it should go down. I like to do it with animations but no luck.  As u can see in my example I only use the `swap A and C position` button to make them swap but that is wrong. I have need to swap them using the up and down button which inside of each div.

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var arr = $scope.arr = [{
    val: 0,
    id: 'a',
    xpos: 0
  }, {
    val: 1,
    id: 'b',
    xpos: 1
  }, {
    val: 2,
    id: 'c',
    xpos: 2
  }];


  $scope.getAbsPos = function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    return {
      left: index * 100 + 'px'
    };
  }

  $scope.swap = function() {
    var a = arr[0];
    var c = arr[1];

    //reorder the array first, since xpos did not change, no animation will be triggered
    arr[0] = c;
    arr[1] = a;

    //update the xpos value in async, which will trigger an animation

    $timeout(function() {
      var tempX = a.xpos;
      a.xpos = c.xpos;
      c.xpos = tempX;

    }, 1)

  }

})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ngApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in arr track by item.id" ng-style="getAbsPos(item.xpos)">{{item.id}} / {{$index}}
      <button ng-click="up()">Move Up</button>
      <button ng-click="down()">Move Down</button>



    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>{{arr}}</div>

    <button style="margin-top:200px" ng-click="swap()">swap A and C position</button>

  </div>
```

The output that I like to achieve is:
Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aite, here's a working solution of what you're looking for. To enable animation, don't forget to include `angular-animate.js` to your index page.

HTML:

```
<div class="cont" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="item.class" id="{{item.id}}">
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <button id="left" ng-click="moveUp(item.track)">Up</button>
        <button id="right" ng-click="moveDown(item.track)">Down</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.cont {position: relative;}
div.first, div.second, div.third {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    /*A bit of animation:*/
    -moz-transition: 0.4s ease all;
    transition: 0.4s ease all;
}
div.first {top:0;}
div.second {top:120px;}
div.third {top:240px;}
#left {float: left;}
#right {float: right;}
h2 {text-align: center;}
#a {background-color: lightblue;}
#b {background-color: lightpink;}
#c {background-color: lightyellow;}
```

ANGULAR:

```
angular.module('myApp', ["ngAnimate"])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {class: "first", track: 0, name: "first", id: "a"},
    {class: "second", track: 1, name: "second", , id: "b"},
    {class: "third", track: 2, name: "third", , id: "c"}
  ];

  $scope.moveUp = function(track){
    //When div is in the top - return;
    if(track == 0) return;

    //Define variables for upper and lower divs:
    var divUp;
    var divDown;

    //Find and assign values to the variables above:
    for(var i = 0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
      if($scope.items[i].track == track) divUp = $scope.items[i]; 
      if($scope.items[i].track == track-1) divDown = $scope.items[i]; 
    }

    //Save class and track values of the element that goes up:
    var classUp = divUp.class;
    var trackUp = divUp.track;

    //Swap class and track values between lower and upper divs:
    divUp.class = divDown.class;
    divDown.class = classUp;
    divUp.track = divDown.track;
    divDown.track = trackUp;
  }

  $scope.moveDown = function(track){
    //When div is in the bottom - return;
    if(track == 2) return;

    //Define variables for upper and lower divs:
    var divUp;
    var divDown;

    //Find and assign values to the variables above:
    for(var i = 0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
      if($scope.items[i].track == track) divDown = $scope.items[i]; 
      if($scope.items[i].track == track+1) divUp = $scope.items[i]; 
    }

    //Save class and track values of the element that goes up:
    var classUp = divUp.class;
    var trackUp = divUp.track;

    //Swap class and track values between lower and upper divs:
    divUp.class = divDown.class;
    divDown.class = classUp;
    divUp.track = divDown.track;
    divDown.track = trackUp;
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some `css` properties (like `float`, `padding`, `margin` etc.) that you need to use to get this result.

By the way, I was fixed your fiddle.

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var arr = $scope.arr = [{
    val: 0,
    id: 'a',
    xpos: 0
  }, {
    val: 1,
    id: 'b',
    xpos: 1
  }, {
    val: 2,
    id: 'c',
    xpos: 2
  }];


  $scope.getAbsPos = function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    return {
      left: index * 100 + 'px'
    };
  }

  $scope.swap = function() {
    var a = arr[0];
    var c = arr[1];

    //reorder the array first, since xpos did not change, no animation will be triggered
    arr[0] = c;
    arr[1] = a;

    //update the xpos value in async, which will trigger an animation

    $timeout(function() {
      var tempX = a.xpos;
      a.xpos = c.xpos;
      c.xpos = tempX;

    }, 1)

  }

})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  /*width: 80px;*/
  width:350px;
  /*height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms;
  transition: all 1000ms;*/
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.item button:first-child {
  float:left;  
}

.item button:last-child {
  float:right;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ngApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in arr track by item.id" ng-style="getAbsPos(item.xpos)">
      <button ng-click="up()">Move Up</button>
      {{item.id}} / {{$index}}
      <button ng-click="down()">Move Down</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>{{arr}}</div>

    <button style="margin-top:200px" ng-click="swap()">swap A and C position</button>

  </div>
</div>
```